# How to avoid unzip "archives were successfully processed." output

Tags: bash, stdout, unzip, stderr

When using the `unzip` command in bash, a lot of output in the terminal is created. Some output can be suppressed by using the `-q` option or the `-qq` ("= even quieter" - UNZIP MAN). However, always a the end of the process I still get a message like `10 archives were successfully processed` (and with an empty line before it).

It seems like this message is from the STDERR, because when I output the STDOUT to a file like

```
unzip -qq files2zip.zip 1> stdoutput.txt
```

It still is outputted to the terminal and not the file. When I output the STDERR (i.e., `2> stderror.txt`)to a file, it does get outputted to the file.

In my script I want errors to be shown on the screen, but I don't want this message to appear. So is there any way to suppress this message without losing the output of the errors (I don't want to output the stderr to a file)?

Comment: What version of `unzip` do you have? Neither *UnZip 6.00 by Debian* on an Ubuntu distro nor *UnZip 6.00 by Info-ZIP* on Red Hat print this message.

Comment: `man unzip` tells me it is v6.0. I'm on Ubuntu and I think I just installed it using apt-get (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use proc sub

```
unzip -qq files2zip.zip 2> >(grep -v "were successfully processed")
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick indeed. I tried something similar, but didn't get the piping correct. So what is the second `>` for? And is there a way to also get rid of the empty line above the message using grep?

Comment: @LuKas `2>` open STDOUT file descriptor to what follows and `>()` allows this stream of data to be sent to a process as though it were a file. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no third output besides standard error and standard output. So the best thing you can do is to filter the unwanted message from stderr, in addition with preceding line. Note, that this assumes particularly structured output of unzip, which might easily break. Something like this:

```
unzip file.zip 2> >(head --lines=-2)
```

Comment: But I do want the (real) errors to be shown in the terminal.